# Cannot change my secure boot configuration in BIOS

Tags: laptop, bios, windows-11, secure-boot, windows-11-v22h2

[image: Problem Image]

- Device: ASUS Vivobook pro 15
- OS: Windows 11 Pro 22H2

As in the image above, the configuration for secure boot has been disabled in my BIOS configuration.

How can I change my secure boot configuration?

Comment: I assume you cannot switch Secure Boot Control from Disabled to Enabled from that screen, that’s how you typically, would enable it.  Which tells me the platform key hasn’t been enrolled. Did this device come with Windows 11?

Comment: This is a free-dos product and I installed the Windows 11 ISO file myself.

Comment: Try updating BIOS (EUFI) .  Always use caution when updating BIOS.

Comment: I know this bios is the latest asus bios.

Comment: @Ramhound If I remember correctly you posted recently a couple of comments about this "FreeDOS" machines and their specific UEFI issues but I couldn't find them now.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - This author only has one question. I don’t recall those comments, even if I did, I am not sure how they would be relevant. I only recall a question about an HP laptop that was missing a TPM.

Comment: @Ramhound It wasn't about this question and yes, it was those ones about the TPM, for sure. Is it the only difference? Thinking about it I would bet this comes set for Legacy (or can FreeDOS be installed in UEFI mode?) and if Legacy/CSM only then it makes sense Secure Boot can't be enabled. I now wonder how the author could have installed Windows 11 under this conditions? Perhaps using one of those Rufus 'hacks'?

Comment: Secure Boot DOES NOT require TPM support. Secure Boot is a feature of uEFI standard

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I try and not speculate. The author should clarify how Windows 11 was installed in the first place.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I try and not speculate. The author should clarify how Windows 11 was installed in the first place.

Comment: I installed Windows 11 ISO file directly on usb and my laptop supports TPM 2.0

Comment: But the thing is: Windows 11 requires Secure Boot enabled (and can't be installed in Legacy/CSM mode). So, how did you do it exactly?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I didn't change any settings without only booting priority. I installed Windows11 on factory-reset state.